# mp3 uploaded to Facebook isn't showing in Facebook app on iPhone or Android

Tags: facebook, upload, mp3

I'm developing an app that allows the user to upload an mp3 file to a facebook friend's wall.  It's all working well.  If I look at the friend's profile page in facebook using IE or Safari, I can see the expected text and the play icon for the mp3 is there.  I can click the play button and hear the audio. But, if I view the friend's profile through the facebook iPhone or Android app, the text appears but the mp3 isn't there.

I've searched high and low for a solution to this and am now stumped! Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"blah:\",\"caption\":\"%@\",\"description\":\"link text\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"mp3\",\"src\":\"http://www.blah.com/audio.mp3\",\"title\":\"song name\",\"artist\":\"singer\",\"href\":\"http://www.blah.com/\"}]}", friendsTableView.chosenName, @" "];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the problem was down to facebook itself rather than my code.  My uploaded files are now showing and playing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that for the last day or so, the embedded mp3 audio player in facebook is broken again so uploaded MP3 files are not playing correctly.  This has been logged with fb: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/163200820438523

It's a mis-leading problem as it's easy to think the bug is in your own code.